# Можно ли сделать похожий sql-запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Можно ли как-то сделать такой запрос с
`Where column1 = 1` ?

```
SELECT 1 AS column1, 'one' AS column2
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'three';
```

Comment: Можно: `SELECT 1 AS column1, 'one' AS column2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя CTE.

**SQL**

```
;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS column1, 'one' AS column2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'two'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'three'
)
SELECT * FROM rs
WHERE column1 = 1;
```